# Detect white spaces chars in the beginning of a string

Tags: python

How can I detect a whitespace indentation in a string ?

I need to parse a CSS file: line by line.
Given that i have a line of CSS style:

```
strong, b { font-weight: normal; color: #000; }
```

How can I extract that whitespace and save it into a variable?

Comment: Your example string does not seem to have any indentation.  What is the desired result you want to save to a variable?

Comment: Provide the result you would like, from your question it's not clear what do you want to achieve

Comment: Ever tried searching for `css parser`? There are lots of resources already

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you want, but you can easily pull the whitespace from the start of a string using regex:

```
import re
def get_whitespace(your_string):
    return re.match(r'\s*',your_string).group()

print len(get_whitespace(' foo')) #1
print len(get_whitespace('bar'))  #0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the leading whitespace from the string without using regex:

```
whitespace = string[ : len(string) - len(string.lstrip())]
```